# Quartz trigger creation migration to 2.2.x

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm working on upgrading Quartz from 1.8.6 to 2.2.x and they've changed quite a few APIs that have broken a fair amount of code.

Previously, a trigger was created like so:

```
LocalTime timeOfDay = schedule.getTimeOfDay();
Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.makeDailyTrigger(timeOfDay.getHourOfDay(), 
       timeOfDay.getMinuteOfHour());
return trigger;
```

Now, using the [migration guide](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/migration-guide), it looks like it's switching to a builder-based system. So I tried doing this:

```
LocalTime timeOfDay = schedule.getTimeOfDay();
    Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
        .withSchedule(cronScheduleDaily(timeOfDay.getHourOfDay(), timeOfDay.getMinuteOfHour()))
        .build();
return trigger;
```

This is essentially coming out of their example from the migration guide that I linked to above.  I'm getting a syntax error on "cronsScheduleDaily" `(The method cronScheduleDaily(int, int) is undefined for the type QuartzUtils)`, which I have no idea where that comes from and I can't find anything online.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: @Taylor It is `The method cronScheduleDaily(int, int) is undefined for the type QuartzUtils`. Updated my original post, thanks.

Comment: So the method cronScheduleDaily doesn't exist.  Probably defined elsewhere in the example.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was thinking too, but it's not. Unless I'm being a blind bat.

Comment: the example has these static imports: `import static org.quartz.DateBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.*;`

Comment: Yeah, I have those as well...hmm, strange.

Comment: Looking at the javadocs I think you want `dailyAtHourAndMinute` ?  http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/CronScheduleBuilder.html#dailyAtHourAndMinute(int, int)

Comment: Yeah, that worked. I had seen that before, but I'm still unsure why they used the `cronScheduleDaily` in their example docs.  Thanks.

Comment: probably just oversight in their tutorial.  Mind if I convert that last comment to an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably an oversight in their docs.  Looking at their java docs, I'd wager you're after `CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute` http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/CronScheduleBuilder.html#dailyAtHourAndMinute(int,%20int)

Comment: Thanks for putting this as an answer so I can accept it. Also, `dailAtHourAndMinute` --> `dailyAtHourAndMinute`